# Can I copy a Python interpreter and rename it without ill effect?

Tags: python

Because of [some asinine problem](https://superuser.com/questions/310335/how-do-i-change-the-file-association-to-a-program-with-the-same-name-in-windows-7) I'm having with multiple Python interpreters and Windows 7, could I simply copy an interpreter, rename it, and run scripts with it without any problems?

My Python 2.6 install came with a `python.exe` and `python26.exe` which are identical according to `fc`.  It seems a convenient arrangement to unambiguously pick a Python version when multiple can be found on the `PATH` envvar, but for some reason those version-tagged `python.exe`'s weren't included in the default 2.7 MSI installer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, depending on what you are doing. You should also be able to move a whole installed interpreter (i.e. the libs and everything) but moving *just* the executable will probably cause you problems.

You might want to create a .bat file that you can use in place of your script that selects the correct interpreter. In that case you can even do things like pick a [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) instance.

```
c:\python26\python.exe c:\tools\myscript.py %*
```

Comment: It's safe to copy the 2.7 version of python.exe to python27.exe.